# Finding minimum dates with certain conditions and then taking the difference

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with IDs, diagnosis code and diagnosis date. A unique patient can have multiple diagnosis dates and codes.

```
ID    |diagnosis_date|diagnosis_code
PT2073|2015-02-28    |5.2
PT2073|2019-02-28    |5.10
PT2013|2015-04-28    |1
PT2013|2017-02-11    |5
PT2013|2017-07-11    |5.10
PT2024|2010-02-11    |5
PT2024|2011-07-11    |3
```

GOAL: Find the minimum date they were diagnosed with disease 1 `diagnosis_code` ilike 5 and the minimum date patient diagnosed with disease 2 `diagnosis_code` ilike 5.1. Disease 2 is a specific type of disease 1 that patients may progress too. I want to find patients who were first diagnosed with disease 1 and then progress to disease 2 in the future.

I tried :

```
from patient_details
group by id
having
    min(case when diagnosis_code ilike '5' then diagnosis_date end)
    < max(case when diagnosis_code ilike  '5.10' then diagnosis_date end)
```

This is just returning all the unique patient ids. I want a count of patients who move from disease one to disease 2 like patient PT2073.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a good use case for window functions...which will allow you to retain whole rows of data with the conditions your looking for instead of just returning ids, where you're currently stuck.

Since you tagged this with redshift, [check out these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html).

But basically, I would:

- pull out the "first diagnosis date" for each combination of patient and code (use row number partitioned by patient id and code, ordered by date desc)
- for each patient, calculate the date difference for the codes you care about in your progression
- filter on the value of that date difference and take the count of that group

So I'm guessing this looks like a subquery to do the row numbering and then at least one outer query do the filter/count.